# How to have more than 2 quotation marks in an xpath statement?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have one single quotation marks and two double quotation marks. How does that work?

```
for c in range(1, 2):

    newcolor= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-attr- 
    0"]/a["c"]').click()
```

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str: String literals are written in a variety of ways: (1) Single quotes: 'allows embedded "double" quotes'. (2) Double quotes: "allows embedded 'single' quotes". (3) Triple quoted: '''Three single quotes''', """Three double quotes""". Triple quoted strings may span multiple lines - all associated whitespace will be included in the string literal..

Answer (score 1):

This is how string inside string defined.
You may enclose the string itself in single quotes.
In this case you have to enclose the inner string, inside the bigger string, with double quotes.
Or vise versa i.e. define the outer string with double quotes and the inner strings with single quotes.
The entire `xpath` expression is a string, the `select-attr-0` and `c` are inner strings enclosed inside the `xpath` expressions string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triple quotes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/triple-quotes-in-python) in such cases ''' or """